# Unable to upload VHD file to Azure Storage

Tags: azure-storage

My query is that how do we upload VHD files to Azure storage?I have used blob storage and select page blob to upload VHD file but receiving this error :

```
RESPONSE Status: 400 Page blob is not supported for this account type.
```

Please advice. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some restrictions on using page blob, you need to use `Hot access tier`, please refer to this [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-pageblob-overview?tabs=dotnet#restrictions).

[image]

This official document has a clearer introduction to the `Access tiers`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-storage-tiers?tabs=azure-portal

You can set the `access tiers` here：

[image]

Comment: That's great  - Before I go through the whole document can you please tell me do I need to create new storage and then select hot tier account type ? thank you

Comment: You only need to change the access tiers of the existing storage account.

Comment: okay got your point because hot access is use for frequent access and queries,  it needs a hot tier account for VHD and SQL database - thank you

Comment: just to update you that i have change cool tier to hot tier in blob storage but still receving the same error : "Page blob is not supported for this account type".
FYI, my vhd size is 400 GB which was converted from vhdx to vhd using hyper-v conversion.But still not able to upload, also treid creating new storage at hot tier.thanks

Comment: Have you tried using `General-purpose v2 accounts`?

Comment: And please select `Premium performance` when creating.

Comment: Yes just created new gen-pur-v2 account and its working now, i am able to upload vhd file.One more thing please. it is possibel to reduce 400 gb vhd size ? thanks a lot

Comment: I don't understand, what does `it is possible to reduce 400 gb vhd size ?` mean?

Comment: My actual VM size was 236 GB(VHDX) after converting it to VHD using Hyper-v the size of VM increase to 400 GB.I want to reduce the size if possible.

Comment: I am not very familiar with this issue, maybe you can post another post.